# MVC3 .NET - When to use client validation scenario

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

After some advice whether my interpretation is correct for the following scenario:

Simple screen which creates/updates (2 separate views - create view and update view) a user record.

Screen contains 3 fields:
Name,
Telephone Number,
National Insurance number (NI Number)

We have validation on:
phone number (to make sure it is correct format)
NI Number (to make sure it is correct format)

There is a Unique Index on NI Number in the database

This is my understanding - totally open to people telling me this is wrong or there is a better way...

So, if a new record is entered, we need to check the NI number is unique - thus we have to POST and run the server side validation - this means that the Javascript validation is irrelevant - and so all the validation has to happen on the server side.

If the record is retrieved from the database and then updated, the client side validation is relevant if the NI number is not updated.

So, I do not need any client side validation routines for the Create view as I always need to make sure the NI Number is unique, whereas, for the update view I do need the client side validation routines as the NI number may not be updated but we will still want to validate the other fields (where neccessary) client side so as to minimise network traffic.

Am I right?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Client-side validation is for basic rules such as required field, phone format, number between  a range, etc. The greatest advantage of client-side validation is that your server will have less overhead (since incompleted forms will never be posted) and will give your customer a better experience since he will not need to wait for the server response.

Server-side validation is for **both basic rules and complex rules** like unique field, lookup at another systems, etc. So, yes, you will duplicate these rules.

I'm currently using [Fluent Validation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) + [Unobtrusive Client Side Validation](http://nraykov.wordpress.com/2011/06/06/asp-net-mvc-3-unobtrusive-client-side-validation/) which enable me to use both client-side and server-side validation without need to duplicate code. If the validation is complex, it wil not be available at the cient, but basic validations will be executed on both sides. And the best of all, I only need to code this rules once. By the way, it also works with Data Annotations which is ASP.NET MVC 3 default validation engine.

Comment: thanks for the quick response - Just to clarify - complex validation like uniqueness ie. NI Number is done on the server and because of this the client side validation code becomes irrelevant in this situation - so let the server undertake all the validation.  The client code is relevant if an existing record is updated and the NI is not changed.

Comment: Why is it irrelevant? Client-side validation prevents a trip to the server when the name or phonenumber are incorrect. Only when those fields are correct, you will have to check the NI on serverside (which also can be done with Ajax ofcourse)